# How to combine the two different into an single array

Tags: php, arrays, key

my code is:

I have set of data in two different variables like an below.

Array 1:

```
Array ( [0] => 15-3 [1] => 16-3 [2] => 15-4 [3] => 16-4 [4] => 15-3 [5] => 16-3 [6] => 15-4 [7] => 16-4 [8] => 15-3 [9] => 16-3 [10] => 15-4 [11] => 16-4 [12] => 15-3 [13] => 16-3 [14] => 15-4 [15] => 16-4 )
```

Array 2:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 11 [5] => 22 [6] => 33 [7] => 44 [8] => 111 [9] => 222 [10] => 333 [11] => 444 [12] => 1111 [13] => 2222 [14] => 3333 [15] => 4444 )
```

In that how can i combine the above two array into an single one array like an below

```
$final_array=Array ( [15-3] => 1 [16-3] => 2 [15-4] => 3 [16-4] => 4 [15-3] => 11 [16-3] => 22 [15-4] => 33 [16-4] => 44 [15-3] => 111 [16-3] => 222 [15-4] => 333 [16-4] => 444 [15-3] => 1111 [16-3] => 2222 [15-4] => 3333 [16-4] => 4444)
```

Comment: $final_array keys should not repeat

Comment: i need all the values wt to do?

Comment: you cannot have two elements with one and the same key ([15-3] for example).

Comment: so there is no solution for thi post @mitkosoft

Comment: yes, it is, but final_array must be multidimensional if you want to keep all values and keys from both arrays.

Comment: ok sent me the answer, thats no prob

Comment: @Rahim using multidimensional array posted as answer

Answer (score 1):

Do a [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$final = array();
foreach($attri_ids_all as $key=>$value){
    $final[$value] = $inventory_code_qty[$key];
}
```

Comment: sorry, the final array should be like this

Comment: Array ( [15-3] => 1111 [16-3] => 2222 [15-4] => 3333 [16-4] => 4444 )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_combine`, you can read about this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Basically you need use:

```
$final_array = array_combine($attri_ids_all, $inventory_code_qty);
```

Comment: array combine is remove duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

It's not complicated at all, juste loop on 1 array...

```
if (count($attri_ids_all) != count($inventory_code_qty)) {
    print 'arrays lenght must be equals';
    return;
}
$final_array = array();
for($i=0 ; $i<count($attri_ids_all) ; $i++) {
    $final_array[$attri_ids_all[$i]] = $inventory_code_qty[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this code you need to foreach loop

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($attri_ids_all as $key=>$value){
    $final_array[$value] = $inventory_code_qty[$key];
}
```

and print **$final_array** array

Comment: Yes i see there is first array value is repeated multiple time so it's not possible  so i suggest to multi dimension array
try this code.
$final_array = array();
for($i=0 ; $i<count($attri_ids_all) ; $i++) {
    $final_array[$i][$attri_ids_all[$i]] = $inventory_code_qty[$i];
}

Answer (score 0):

**using multidimensional array**

```
$result_array = array();
foreach($attri_ids_all as $key=>$value){
    $result_array[$key][$value] = $inventory_code_qty[$key];
}
```

Comment: after that how can i merge all values

Answer (score 0):

```
    function foo($key, $val) {
      return array($key=>$val);
    }
    $arrResult = array_map('foo', $attri_ids_all, $inventory_code_qty);

    echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrResult);
echo "</pre>";
```